# Is there a way to list arguments to a method as a collection?

Tags: groovy

If I have a method such as this:

```
void someMethod(int one, int two, int three) 
{
  log.debug("One = ${one}, two = ${two}, three = ${three}")
}
```

Is there a way to avoid listing each param in the debit message? I want to print out values for all the parameters without necessarily listing each one separately.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use varargs:

```
void someMethod( int... args ) {
    println "Args = $args"
}
```

Worried about more than 3 arguments getting used while calling method? Then make sure you only deal with `args[0]` till `args[2]` inside the method.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use interceptor construct:

```
class Sample {
    void someMethod(int one, int two, int three) {
//        println("One = ${one}, two = ${two}, three = ${three}")
    }
}

class SampleInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    boolean doInvoke() {
        true
    }

    Object beforeInvoke(Object obj, String name, Object[] args) {
        if(name == "someMethod")
            println args
    }

    Object afterInvoke(Object obj, String name, Object[] args, Object result) {
        result
    }
}

def proxy = ProxyMetaClass.getInstance(Sample)
def interceptor = new SampleInterceptor()
proxy.interceptor = interceptor

proxy.use {
    def h = new Sample()
    h.someMethod(1,2,3)
}
```

Have a look at the [sample](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/11/groovy-goodness-intercept-methods-with.html).